# Call pactl with Java Process doesn't work

Tags: sound, java, pulseaudio

I'm using the `Process` Java class to call `pactl` functions. Specifically I want to change the volume of a sink input. It worked a few days ago, but now it doesn't anymore. I tried executing other commands and they worked fine. pactl also doesn't return any error messages. It seems like it is executed but it doesn't change anything. 
Even calling a shell script that executes the command didn't work.

When I copy the command directly in the terminal it works. What am I missing?

```
Process p = null;
try {
    String command = "pactl set-sink-input-volume 0 " + volumeNew + "%";
    System.out.println(command);
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
            "/bin/bash",
            "-c",
            command });

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println("line: " + s);
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Ended");
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
pactl set-sink-input-volume 0 59%
Ended
```